# Verifying function call and inspecting arguments using sinon spies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I would like to verify that `bar()` is called inside `foo()` from my unit test.

I figured that [Sinon spies](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies-api) might be suitable, but I don't know how to use them.

Is there any way to check that the method is called? Perhaps even extracting the arguments used in the `bar()` call?

```
var spy = sinon.spy(foo);

function foo(){
    bar(1,2,3);
}

function bar(){ }

foo();

// what to do with the spy?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8by9jg07/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In your case, you are trying to see if `bar` was called, so you want to spy `bar` rather than `foo`.

As described in the [doc](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.2/spies/) :

```
function bar(x,y) {
  console.debug(x, y);
}
function foo(z) {
  bar(z, z+1);
}
// Spy on the function "bar" of the global object.
var spy = sinon.spy(window, "bar");

// Now, the "bar" function has been replaced by a "Spy" object
// (so this is not necessarily what you want to do) 

foo(1);

bar.getCall(0).args => should be [1,2]
```

Now, spying on the internals of the function strongly couples your test of "foo" to its implementation, so you'll fall into the usual ["mockist vs classical"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#ClassicalAndMockistTesting) debate.

Comment: According to [the doc](http://sinonjs.org/docs) it should be `getCall(0)` instead of `getCalls(0)`

Comment: And finally you can assert the call arguments easily like this:  `expect(window.bar.getCall(0).args).deep.equal([1, 2]);`

Answer (score 17):

I agree with Adrian in saying that you probably wanted to spy on bar instead.

```
var barSpy = sinon.spy(bar);
```

Then to check that it was called once

```
assert(barSpy.calledOnce);
```

Just called at all

```
assert(barSpy.called)
```

Called x amount of times

```
assert.equal(barSpy.callCount, x);
```

If you want to extract the arguments from the first call of the spy:

```
var args = barSpy.getCalls()[0].args
```

Then you can do what you want with those arguments.

Comment: This answer is technically wrong. You can't [use `spy()` this way](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/v2.3.6/lib/sinon/spy.js#L19) - it takes an object and a method name as argument 1 and 2 (this was also the case for older versions back in 2015). If called with only a function it [creates an anonymous spy function named after the passed one](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/v2.3.6/lib/sinon/spy.js#L135) and returns it, the passed reference is not altered.

Comment: @try-catch-finally Is it ok for you to post the technically correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be spying on bar, rather than foo?

```
var spy = sinon.spy(bar)
```

Call foo:

```
foo()
```

Check bar was called:

```
console.log(spy.calledOnce)
```

Comment: This answer is technically wrong. You can't [use `spy()` this way](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/v2.3.6/lib/sinon/spy.js#L19) - it takes an object and a method name as argument 1 and 2 (this was also the case for older versions back in 2015). If called with only a function it [creates an anonymous spy function named after the passed one](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/v2.3.6/lib/sinon/spy.js#L135) and returns it, the passed reference is not altered.