# Sinon spy on function expression

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, function-expression

is it possible to make sinon spy on function expressions? Look this code for example.

```js
function one() { return 1; }
function two() { return 2; }
function three() { return 3; }

function myMethod() {
  var n1 = one();
  var n2 = two();
  var n3 = three();
  return n1 + n2 + n3;
}


QUnit.module('My test');

QUnit.test('testing functions', (assert) => {
  assert.expect(3);
  
  const spyOne = sinon.spy(one);
  const spyTwo = sinon.spy(two);
  const spyThree = sinon.spy(three);
 myMethod();

  assert.ok(spyOne.called, "called one");
  assert.ok(spyTwo.called, "called two");
  assert.ok(spyThree.called, "called three");
  
  sinon.restore();
});
```

Even though I call `myMethod()` and I have spies on `one - two - three` I still get false on `one.called` (same for `two` and `three`)

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verifying function call and inspecting arguments using sinon spies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800733/verifying-function-call-and-inspecting-arguments-using-sinon-spies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `sinon.spy(fn)` doesn't change `fn`, it merely creates a *new* function (the spy) that will call `fn`.

For you to be able to test `one`, `two`, `three`, you need to replace those functions (or rather, their references) with spies, and restore them afterwards:

```
// keep references to the original functions
var _one   = one;
var _two   = two;
var _three = three;

// replace the original functions with spies
one   = sinon.spy(one);
two   = sinon.spy(two);
three = sinon.spy(three);

// call our method
myMethod();

// test
assert.ok(one.called,   "called one");
assert.ok(two.called,   "called two");
assert.ok(three.called, "called three");

// restore the original functions
one   = _one;
two   = _two;
three = _three;
```

It's not ideal though, and if possible I would probably group all the functions into an object. That would also enable Sinon to restore the originals itself.

Comment: This only works if you have the function definitions and test in the same file, which is rarely the case.

Comment: @GovindRai correct, but I'm not offering a solution for that particular issue. I'm just explaining why the original code in the question doesn't work as expected and how to work around that.