# JavaScript: Unit Testing Factory Function Default Parameters

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Here is a simple factory function that I want to test using Mocha to make sure that it is run with the proper default parameters.

I had the intuition that Sinon Spies were the right tools for the job but it seems, from the documentation and online examples that they only work on object methods?!

```
function foo (bar=baz) {
  // do something with bar here
  // more code...
  return somethingOtherThanBar
}
```

The test should enable me to check that **bar** is indeed **baz**.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think a spy would be able to get you the default argument value, since the spy works on the incoming arguments (which you omit for default values)

Comment: You can't and should not check the default values but what your function returns or how it interacts instead. Feed different (or no) values in and observe how it interacts or what it returns. And yes, you can't directly spy functions. There might be a way to reference the global scope (`window`) though (_though I'd discourage using the global namespace_). See the related question: [Verifying function call and inspecting arguments using sinon spies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800733/verifying-function-call-and-inspecting-arguments-using-sinon-spies/33129455#comment76811134_33129455).

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs. I would definitely not go with the global namespace option. Also I understand that I should focus on testing function outputs instead of internal logics.